# pass post value from one php to another php page

Tags: php, file, post

I have 2 php scripts one that takes the values from a form on an html page and just return them to the user so he can check they are correct i then want to allow him to confirm then by pressing a submit button, the values will then be written on a txt file.
Here is my code that i have so far, the script return that the values are being written on the file but there is nothing in the file>

code:
fist php:

```
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
<div id="oneConatiner">
    <h1>Please confirm the details of your order:</h1>
    <div align="left" id='php'>
    <form name="info" method="post" action="confirmation.php">
        <p>Your surname is: <?php echo $surname . "<p>"; ?>
        <p>Your lastname is: <?php echo $lastname . "</p></div>"; ?>
        <p>Your email is: <?php echo $mail . "<p>"; ?>
        <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Confirm" /></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Second php:

```
<?php
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $page = ceil($quantity / 10);
    $data = "$surname,$lastname,$mail\r\n";
    $fh = fopen("user.txt", "a");    
    fwrite($fh, $data);
    fclose($fh); 
    if (fwrite == FALSE){
        echo "fail";        
    } else {
        echo "successful";
    }        
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The values you want to submit need to be form inputs of some kind. I'll use text fields for this example:

```
<form name="info" method="post" action="confirmation.php">
    <p>Your surname is: <input name="surname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($surname); ?>"></p>
    <p>Your lastname is: <input name="lastname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($lastname); ?>"></p>
    <p>Your email is: <input name="mail" value="<?php echo htmlentities($mail); ?>"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Confirm" /></p>
</form>
```

If you don't want these fields to be editable, you can either set the fields to readonly or use hidden inputs instead.

Answer (score 0):

The only error that I see and needs to be corrected is that the word fwrite in the if-conditional should be changed to $fh otherwise the code works. It worked for me.

Make sure the $surname, $lastname and $mail are not empty and you have read and write permissions for the folder where user.txt is supposed to be stored.